# How to customize dashboard with bing maps

Tags: bing-maps

I have

```
showDashboard : true
```

It creates the map navigator in the upper left corner.

I have a sidebar there. I would like to move the navigator to the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the default CSS of the Bing Maps Nav bar:

```
.OverlaysTL {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 160px !important;
}
```